# How do I programmatically resize and change position of a window

Tags: java, windows, attributes

How to resize (and change the position) of a window of other application programmatically? I would like to code with Java, and I want to resize all windows, not only those which are created by JVM. I'm using Windows XP. I would like to change other properties of those windows if there are more options.

Additional information after comments:

Q: Why do you want to do that?
A: Windows lacks feature to move window across multiple displays **fast**. Have you tried WinSplit Revolution 9.02? It has some great features move/position window with just few button presses. You don't need to grab a mouse at all.

Comment: Any ideas? Maybe you've seen some open-source java project, so I could look at the code?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't control other applications using java, you can however, control windows you've created yourself

Comment: This is the first time ever I've seen a migration **to** SO rather than from it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do anything with windows who are not your own in *pure java* would be the `java.awt.Robot` class. But it also does not offer any useful API for your goal, so you only could do a screenshot, analize the results, and then position, press, move and release the mouse accordingly - thus, do the same as a human user would do.

If you want more, your would have to get system-specific. I think both the Windows API and the X protocol (ant thus the X client libraries) offer at least the ability to get informations about other program windows, I don't know about changing them. (I suppose Mac OS has such capabilities, too.)

This usually would mean writing at least the basics of this functionality in C (or any other language which access to such a library) and then use JNI to access this from Java. You could also use a JNI-wrapping library like JNA (Java Native access) to leave out the JNI step.